# pjax submit form URL redirection

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, pushstate, pjax

[PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)'s documentation states that Github uses `$.pjax.submit()` in [submitting a Gist form](https://gist.github.com/gists). A desired feature of an ajax form submission which Github nicely implements is that the URL redirects from the form's `action` to a newly created URL (in this case, one containing the newly server-side created gist ID).

For example, from this:

```
https://gist.github.com/gists //  form action
```

to this:

```
https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/5019589 //assume this ID is generated server side
```

I've gotten this to work similarly on my site (i.e., the page itself redirects to the equivalent of https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/5019589) but I can't redirect the URL (it stays like https://gist.github.com/gists).

Is this entirely a server-side issue (setting headers?) or is there something in pjax that I'm missing? I'm using a version of pjax I downloaded today so it can't be that i'm using a buggier version of pjax.

Answer (score 5):

Did you find any solution to this?
I had the similar issue.

Basically you need to set X-PJAX-URL property in response header.
It's value should be same as Request URL.

In Laravel, I did it like this...

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
  $response->headers->set('X-PJAX-URL', $request->getRequestUri());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more-elegant / proper way to do this with $.pjax.submit(), but this is the solution I've been using without any problems.  I serialize the form inputs prior to submission, then POST them to my server.  Then check the reply from the server to make sure I don't need to prevent the user from going forward before calling my PJAX to continue.

```
$("#save").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  dataString = $("#form").serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#form").attr("action"),
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
      // Handle the server response (display errors if necessary)

      $.pjax({
        timeout: 2000,
        url: data.url,
        container: '#main-content'
      });

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks yeah that's exactly what I'm doing too as a hack solution. The question is is whether this can be accomplished with 2 AJAX requests or just 1. It'd obviously be better to have just one request, where the `data.url` was pushed to the browser bar just like the content was pushed to `#main-content`. Now that I'm looking at it, Github Gist appears to be doing the same thing as us in making 2 requests though they are doing PJAX(POST)->PJAX(GET) and we are doing AJAX(POST)->PJAX(GET). The bottom line is that it would seem more performant to do only 1 request (continued in next comment...).

Comment: I'm just not sure if doing this in 1 request is possible with PJAX or whether it requires a server-side hack that I'm not aware of (I'm using PHP/Codeigniter and doing a 301/302 redirect with AJAX requests doesn't change the URL, maybe its not possible in any language/framework?).

Answer (score 0):

It happens if response HTML doesn't contain initial PJAX container